# How to add startup script to windows VM instance Google

Tags: google-compute-engine

I wanto to add startup script to windows VM instance Google (windows server 2012 datacenter).

I added statup script by custom metadata:

- Key: **startup-script**
- Value: **#!/bin/bash  mkdir C:\newfolder**

But, it was not working. No folder was created in C: disk.

Serial port 1 (console) output:

*2018/05/10 07:07:51 GCEMetadataScripts: Starting startup scripts (version 4.1.6@1).
2018/05/10 07:07:51 GCEMetadataScripts: No startup scripts to run.*

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use the Windows specific keys like `windows-startup-script-ps1`.
See https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#providing_startup_script_contents_directly

Comment: Hi, do you know any idea on this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65342169/gce-windows-startup-script?noredirect=1#comment115523860_65342169 . It is more or less related to the same issue here

Answer (score 0):

Thank user835611 so much.

I did it.

I encounter another problem when running a complex script: download exe file from link and run it.

My script:

http://hayketnoi.com/abc.exe C: \ abc.exe

C: \ abc.exe

abc.exe is a winform application and I did not have a remote desktop at that time.

Any solution for my case?
I'm doing this well with Vultr's VPS system.